# PHP Regex to Show Links or URLS

Tags: php, wordpress, hyperlink

I has wordpress theme i create Link Post Format and then i want regex php expression to show me only the links and i don't want show me the text or any excerpt text or any images.

i create the regex code as below

```
$pattern = '/.*?(http\:\/\/www\.[a-zA-Z0-9\.\/\-]+)/';
$subject = get_the_content();

preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```

but this code don't return to any links or urls. please help me and i want the pattern to return or print only the links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to extract all the urls from `$subject` ? If so, try something like this :

```
$subject = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, http://example1.com  consectetur adipisicing elit, http://example2.com";
preg_match_all('#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#', $subject, $matches);
    $all_urls = $matches[0];
    print_r($all_urls);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Array
(
    [0] => http://example1.com
    [1] => http://example2.com
)
```

Comment: your pattern show me this error preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier '/'